# Ruby Variable Interpolation in Array Names

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation, ruby-3.1

I have a few similarly named arrays and I need to loop through the array names:

```
level_1_foo
level_2_foo
level_3_foo
level_4_foo
level_5_foo
```

I'd like to do something like the following where `x` is the value of the digit in the array name:

```
(1..5).each do |x|
  level_x_foo << some-value
end
```

Can this be done?
I've tried `"level_#{x}_foo"`, `level_+x+_foo`, and a couple others, to no success.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of multiple local variables, a common approach is to use an Array or Hash instead where you can use the level as an index as appropriate, e.g. `data = {1 => some_value, 2 => some_other_value}` You can then easily access the data with `data[1]`. Having to "dynamically" access a variable is generally an anti-pattern and should be replaced with actual data structures (which is also much faster usually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to retrieve the arrays with `binding.local_variable_get`:

```
(1..5).each do |x|
  binding.local_variable_get("level_#{x}_foo") << some-value
end
```

You could also do it with `eval`, but the above approach minimizes the code that is dynamically evaluated.

Comment: Thank you!  I came across `eval` after I posted my question.  I also read it was sketchy to use it.  I had not seen the `binding.local_variable_get()` before.  And now I know.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```
# Initialize a hash
levels = {}

# Initialize your arrays
(1..5).each do |x|
   levels["level_#{x}_foo"] = []
end

# Now you can access your arrays like this
(1..5).each do |x|
  levels["level_#{x}_foo"] << 'some-value'
end
```